# Check if variable contents exist in array displayed in table?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, html-table

I am creating an in-house order pulling application. I'm pulling form an ODBC source and placing items in an array. I'm then creating a new flat file for each order being physically worked on. When the user scans/enters an item from that order number it places that item on a new line in the order file that was created.

I'm then reading that order file back to get the items that have been scanned thus far. Where I'm stuck is how to mark that line item that exist in the order file as being completed in the HTML table.

Here is the pertinent code as it relates to my question:

```
$file_array = file_get_contents($file_ordnumber, "rb");
$items_array = explode("\n",$file_array);

echo "<table>";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($location_array); $i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    if (in_array("$itemno_array[$i]", $items_array)) {
        echo "<td>$itemno_array[$i] EXISTS</td>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<td>$itemno_array[$i] NO EXIST</td>";
    }
//  echo "<td>$location_array[$i]</td>";
    echo "<td>$qty_array[$i]";
    echo "<td>$pickingseq_array[$i]</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

As you can see I'm iterating through the array and displaying it in a HTML table. I'm curious why my above code isn't working. My result ends up being from the 'else' statement thus ALL lines, even if they exist in the file is showing as "NO EXIST" which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: why do you call a variable contains plain text a "file **array**"?

Comment: It's just the name I chose for the variable since I'm eventually placing the contents of the file into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your Print_r($items_arr); 
also try using **`isset($arrayVar[$key]`**
and try removing double quotes and see if it works.. like ...

```
$file_array = file_get_contents($file_ordnumber, "rb");
$items_array = explode("\n",$file_array);

echo "<table>";

for ($i = 0; $i < count($location_array); $i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    if (in_array($itemno_array[$i], $items_array)) {
        echo "<td>".$itemno_array[$i]." EXISTS</td>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<td>".$itemno_array[$i]." NO EXIST</td>";
    }
//  echo "<td>".$location_array[$i]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$qty_array[$i]."";
    echo "<td>".$pickingseq_array[$i]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Removing the double quotes didn't work. Here is the output that you requested:

Array ( [0] => 49-51 [1] => 8M-16740 [2] => )

Comment: BTW, using isset gives me the opposite result...it tells me that all items EXIST. Perhaps the count variable isn't working properly here?

Comment: Adding to this, it should be noted that the keys do not match in the arrays. I want to search for the values only and disregard the keys. Keys are important in the table in that I'm pulling from a database and need them in a certain order, but for comparing the arrays I just want to look at the value.

The full array created from the database for this example: Array ( [0] => 8M-16740 [1] => 8A-7650358-PR [2] => 8BA-8349 [3] => 1BA-8344 [4] => 0A-7651338-PR [5] => 49-51 [6] => [7] => )

Answer (score 0):

I got this resolved by going about it a different way. I use strpos() to search the flat file itself rather than the array that I exploded from it:

```
echo "<table>";

//for ($i = 0; $i < count($itemno_array); $i++)
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($itemno_array);$i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
//  if (in_array($itemno_array[$i], $items_array)) {
    echo "<td>";
    $var = $itemno_array[$i];
    $newvar = trim($var);
    if(strpos($file_array, $newvar ) !==FALSE) {
        echo "$var ** EXISTS</td>";
    }
    else {
        echo "$var DOES NOT EXIST **</td>";
    }
//  echo "<td>$location_array[$i]</td>";
    echo "<td>$qty_array[$i]";
    echo "<td>$pickingseq_array[$i]</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```